# Hyperledger Composer + loopback-datasource-juggler + Java: Encoding Problems

Tags: java, loopback, hyperledger-composer

I developed a Business Network Definition with **Hyperledger Composer**, deployed it on a *Hyperledger Fabric* example-chain (running locally on a *VirtualBox*-installation of Ubuntu with Docker-containers) and started Composer's REST-server with `composer-rest-server` (and options `-c [cardname] -n always -w true`). Then I played a bit in the browser and all is working fine.

Now comes the problematic bit: I want to write a **Java**-program interacting with this REST API and somehow the API seems unable to parse my Java-sent requests. I copied the **JSON**-string that Java produces to the browser, ran it there and it worked fine. But if I send it programmatically I get the error (see at the end).

This is what I send through the browser

```
{"cId":"C_ID7","cDomain":"example.com"}
```

The browser tells me with CURL it should look like this

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"cId":"C_ID7","cDomain":"example.com"}' 'http://localhost:3000/api/com.example.Company'
```

Now I want to send the same message through Java+JSOUP with the following code:

```
Response resp = Jsoup.connect(baseURL + namespace + "Company").ignoreContentType(true).method(Method.POST)
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            .requestBody("{\"cId\":\"C_ID7\",\"cDomain\":\"example.com\"}").execute();
```

The same (without the requestBody and Method.GET) works for GET-requests. `ignoreContentType(true)` is necessary, because JSOUP will not handle 'application/json', see [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/791). `ignoreHttpErrors(true)` is necessary, to get through the Http 500 error, which conceals the true error, which I need for trouble-shooting.

So then finally what I see, when I execute the above code, is the following error:

```
    {"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"Property names containing dot(s) are not supported. Model: com_example_Company, dynamic property: {\"cId\":\"C_ID7\",\"cDomain\":\"example.com\"}","stack":"Error: Property names containing dot(s) are not supported. Model: com_example_Company, dynamic property: {\"cId\":\"C_ID7\",\"cDomain\":\"example.com\"}\n    at com_example_Company.ModelBaseClass._initProperties 
  (/home/[user]

    ]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:249:17)\n    
        at com_example_Company.ModelBaseClass (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:60:8)\n    
        at com_example_Company.Model (eval at createModelClassCtor   
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)\n    
        at com_example_Company.PersistedModel (eval at createModelClassCtor 
        (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)\n    
        at new com_example_Company (eval at createModelClassCtor  
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)\n    
        at Function.DataAccessObject.create (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:359:13)\n    
        at SharedMethod.invoke 
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/shared-method.js:270:25)\n    
        at HttpContext.invoke (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/http-context.js:297:12)\n    
        at phaseInvoke (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:676:9)\n    at runHandler 
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:135:5)\n    
        at iterate (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)\n    
        at Object.async.eachSeries 
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:162:9)\n    
        at runHandlers (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:144:13)\n    
        at iterate 
      (/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)\n    
        at /home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25\n    
        at /home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:154:25"}}
```

where obviously [user] is my username. So I had a look at the **loopback-datasource-juggler** sources and found that in `model-builder.js` ([source on Github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/model-builder.js)) instead of parsing the different properties of the string, it is given the complete string ("{\"cId\":\"C_ID7\",\"cDomain\":\"example.com\"). In line 269 the builder checks whether there are dot-characters in the property-name. Since in our case the property name is the complete JSON-string, there are dots and the program fails.

Unfortunately XML does not seem to be supported at this point.

Now: **How can this happen?** My only guess is an encoding thing done by Java, because the same JSON works in the browser. Any ideas what could have caused this?

And one smaller issue: The error message in the code is ''Property names containing dot(s) are not supported. ' + 'Model: %s, property: %s'', but in the error I receive it says something about "dynamic property". **Am I at the wrong point for searching what causes the error?**

Comment: If I replace the '.' by a '_', I get the error
"Unprocessable Entity
{"error":{"statusCode":422,"name":"ValidationError","message":"The `com_example_Company` instance is not valid. Details: `cId` can't be blank (value: undefined); `cDomain` can't be blank (value: undefined).","details":{"context":"com_example_Company","codes":{"cId":["presence"],"cDomain":["presence"]}, ...."

Comment: I "fixed" it by using the standard HttpURLConnection and sending the same string that was previously sent with JSOUP. However, I leave this open in case someone may have an idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already specified `'Content-Type: application/json'`, you needn't have double quotes in the requestBody. The following should work:

```
Response resp = Jsoup.connect(baseURL + namespace + "Company").ignoreContentType(true).method(Method.POST)
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            .requestBody({\"cId\":\"C_ID7\",\"cDomain\":\"example.com\"}).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

the curl example is what the REST APIs (rather than merely the browser) know about the business network REST API endpoints.

for your requestBody, you will need the fully qualified class (ie meaning asset/participant/transaction class with leading namespace) - an example is :

curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "$class": "org.example.biznet.SampleAsset", \ 
   "assetId": "1", \ 
   "value": "103300" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3000/api/SampleAsset'

So yours will be something like

Response resp = Jsoup.connect(baseURL + namespace + "Company").ignoreContentType(true).method(Method.POST)
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            .requestBody("{\"\$class\": \"org.example.biznet.SampleAsset\", \"cId\":\"C_ID7\", \"cDomain\":\"example.com\"}").execute();

I believe you also needed at least one other double-quotes (total above now : 14) and a closing curly bracket in addition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the problem. The $class is optional: I tried it without the class (because it is already encoded in the URL) and it works in the browser. I also added it in the code: No changes.

Comment: ok cool, you're welcome - as you wrote: "My only guess is an encoding thing done by Java, because the same JSON works in the browser."  If the same sequence works in the browser as posted  and with the namespace notation as used there, then it should in theory be transportable.